# Schema for Folder/Directory Structure of Zip File

Tags: validation, directory, zip, schema, posix

Is there a standard schema language to validate structure of folders/directories?

Kind of like XML Schema but instead of XML files, it's for a files in a directory?

For example, a schema for files in a zip file.

Comment: This question is unclear. How would you *validate structure of folders/directories*? Anyone can name a folder anything they'd like, in any order, as long as it meets the requirements of the operating system's naming conventions. What would you validate it against?

Comment: for instance, folder/zip-file must contain a _drafts_ folder. Must contain a _index.txt_ file.

Comment: There's no schema for that - why would you think there would be?

Comment: While there doesn't seem to be a universal standard for this, you should be able to define a schema for your directory structure in JSON which can then be validated with [directory-schema-validator](https://jpoehnelt.github.io/directory-schema-validator/).